# References displayed as"?"

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

I am creating a IEEE paper, but all my references are displayed as [?]. Why is that? What can I do to get the references properly typeset?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,twoside]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}
\title{DDD}
\author{AAA}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
 hhh
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
 hghg \cite{vvv}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{myreference}
\end{document}
```

and here is my `.bib` file:

```
@article{vvv,
  author  = {xxx},
  title   = {cryptography},
  journal = {dddd},
  year    = {2012},
  volume  = {CS},
  number  = {04},
  pages   = {161}
},
```

Comment: Are you running the needed sequence of: latex, bibtex, latex, latex ?  If you are using a GUI editor, make sure it knows how to run bibtex as well.

Comment: I experience no problems -- in particular, the entry is displayed correctly in the References section and the citation callout shows up as `[1]` -- if I run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more on your code.

Comment: I am using Texmaker. some of the are saying it has to be compiled.How to do that.I am new to this area ,so I dont know what you mean by latex, bibtex, latex, latex order.How to run bibtex???

Comment: Tools --> BibTeX.

Comment: workingg..now got the idea

Comment: On that basis it's  a duplicate